# How can I restart a VPN whenever I connect via wireless or 3G/4G?

Tags: wifi, openvpn, network-interface, 3g, lte

How can I restart a VPN whenever I connect to the Internet via a HotSpot or through a 3G/4G modem.

My distro is Ubuntu Precise 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to start a script every time a particular interface goes online. Where they are depend on your distribution (please specify).  There is also an easier option (which may or may not work), the "Use VPN..." option in the NetworkManager (Edit Connections menu).  Are you using this last option and it does not work?

Depending on what you use to connect, these are possible locations for hooks (scripts to be called upon an event such as a network connection): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Using_hooks

Another way is to write a udev rule: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Writing_udev_rules

Or, if you use ifupdown (Debian/Ubuntu) then you can look at `/etc/network/interfaces` to set up hooks, see also http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/ .

Comment: I am using  Ubuntu Precise. I'd also prefer to use something scripted, not something done through a GUI

Comment: I don't have a Debian-based machine here to test, but you should be able to work with the last option. Please see here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/ and things in it like `up /usr/local/bin/myconfigscript`. If you need more help please post your configuration file.